# Pair Value Reading Errors C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, compiler-errors, std-pair

I am getting the compiler error:

> error: request for member 'first' in 'list.std::map::operator[],
>   std::less, std::allocator > > >((* &0.0)).std::pair::second', which is
>   of non-class type 'int'  int closestX = list[0].second.first;

when trying to read data from a map called list defined and with iterator as:

```
map<double, pair<int, int>> list;
map<double, pair<int, int>>::iterator it = list.begin();
```

Members in list are inserted with:

```
list.insert(it, pair<double, pair<int, int>>(findDistance(posr,posc,j, i), pair<int, int>(j, i)));
```

I am reading the value from the map using:

```
int closestX = list[0].second.first;
int closestY = list[0].second.second;
```

The error seems to indicate that the return type of `list[0].second.first` is non class type int, but that return type matches perfectly with the value type of closestX, and I have now hit a wall. Assume list[0] is initialized and holds a valid value.

Comment: `list` is a bad name. People could easily mistake this for `std::list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error seems to indicate that the return type of list[0].second.first is non class type int

No, the error message is telling that `list[0].second` is not class type so you can not perform `.first` on it.

Note that [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will return the `mapped_type`.

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key.

```
list                 => map<double, pair<int, int>>
list[0]              => pair<int, int>
list[0].second       => int
list[0].second.first => failed
```

Comment: but the list was initialized with pair<double, pair<int, int>>

Comment: @Stephen Your "list" is a map, an associative container. And it was initialized with two arguments (double and pair<int, int>), but not a pair<double, pair<int, int>>

Comment: @Stephen That's how `std::map::operator[]` works, it will return the *value* mapped to the specified *key*, i.e. the `mapped_type`, not the whole `value_type`.

Comment: Ok, that makes much more sense after the edit. But then how would I get the value of the first key?

Comment: @Stephen [`std::map::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin) will return the iterator points ot the first element of the map. `a_map.begin()->first` will return the key, `a_map.begin()->second` will return the mapped_value, i.e. `pair<int, int>`.

Comment: I mean the double value, what I was attempting to do was insert elements with a key that was of type double and a mapped value of type pair<int,int>, did I do that wrong?

Comment: Ok sorry for mixing this all up but I understand after your last comment

Comment: @Stephen Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

`list[0]` is already of value type `pair<int, int>`, not of the iterator type. So you could write

```
int closestX = list[0].first;
int closestY = list[0].second;
```

Comment: Wouldnt list[0] be of type <double, pair<int,int>> though? I thought that both values were stored in a map.

Comment: @Stephen thats not a type, its just a collection of template parameters. For a `map` `operator[]` returns `mapped_type` which is just a typedef for the second template parameter i.e. `pair<int, int>`.

Comment: @PaulRooney Apologies, wouldnt it be of type pair<double, pair<int,int>>

Comment: No take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) look at the various template parameters and the return value of `operator[]`. What you are describing is the `value_type`, which is the type that is used when inserting into the map using `insert`.